# Fetching repeated customer details from different databses in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need some suggestions on how we can fetch customer details which are repeated more than two times over a period of 2 months. The table design is same, however these tables belong to **different database schema** . Looking forward for help.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

simple, use a for loop for 2 iterations and pass two database names in an array and pass it to that for loop. You can search two databases. 
example:
$databases = ['database1', 'database2'];

for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

```
usn = '';
pwd = '';
database = '.$databases[i].';
```

}